# Failure of Arzelà-Ascoli when some hypotheses are dropped

Tags: real-analysis, arzela-ascoli

Let $C$ be the space of continuous functions $K \to M$, where $K$ is a compact space, $M$ is a compact metric space. Equip $C$ with the obvious metric. The Arzelà-Ascoli theorem says that any equicontinuous family $F \subset C$ is relatively compact. One can do so by appealing to Lebesgue's number lemma to show that its closure is totally bounded.

I want to study extent to which the Arzelà-Ascoli fails if we drop some of its hypotheses. For instance, is there an example of a sequence in $C$ that is (a) Cauchy, (b) pointwise convergent, but (c) not convergent to a point in C? (Obviously, the points of any such sequence are not contained in any equicontinuous family.)

Comment: In terms of just a counterexample to AA when you drop equicontinuity, you can look at $f_n(x)=\sin(nx)$ on any nontrivial interval. The assumption of Cauchiness can't be there, because $C(K,M)$ with the uniform metric is complete. Once you drop that assumption, if you want pointwise convergence then you can look at $f_n(x)=x^n$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @Ian: Ah, yeah, I forgot that $C$ is complete. (I duly reproved it after saw you mention it.) Sorry and thanks!